# XMLHttpRequest 401 (Unauthorized)

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I am trying to Create Post in user interface.
When I logged in as Admin and insert

```
createPost.setRequestHeader("X-WP-Nonce", magicalData.nonce);
```

to the below code, Create Post success. But I don't want to use nonce, I want use user and password, but I got this error: 401 (Unauthorized). I tried to replace btoa to Decode64 but it not work. Do I miss anything?

```
var createPost = new XMLHttpRequest();

createPost.open("POST", magicalData.siteURL + "/wp-json/wp/v2/posts", true);
createPost.withCredentials = true;
createPost.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("username:password"));

createPost.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
createPost.send(JSON.stringify(ourPostData));
createPost.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (createPost.readyState == 4) {
    if (createPost.status == 201) {
      document.querySelector('.admin-quick-add [name="title"]').value = '';
      document.querySelector('.admin-quick-add [name="content"]').value = '';
    } else {
      alert("Error - try again.");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If the server is expecting 'X-wp-nonce' you have to provide the same in your headers, others will be ignored